# Average age calculator using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am trying to calculate the average of age (year + month format) using Python3. I loaded an excel file and wrote the code below:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta

import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelFile

today = date.today()

agefile = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name = "birthdate")

age = pd.to_datetime(agefile["birthdate"], format = "%d/%m/%Y")

average_age = sum(((today - x) for x in age), timedelta(0)) / len(age)
```

And the last line didn't work. It gave me an error message like this:

```
descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'datetime.date'
```

I spent a huge amount of time figuring out what the problem was, but I have not found relevant answer so far. Can you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Pandas, you should aim to use vectorised computations rather than converting to regular Python `datetime` objects. Internally, Pandas `pd.Timestamp` objects are represented by integers and hence enable efficient calculations.

Therefore, you can do the following:

```
# create series of dates containing birthdates
birthdate = pd.to_datetime(agefile['birthdate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# subtract from today's date
age = pd.to_datetime('today') - birthdate

# calculate average age
avg_age = age.mean()
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
s = pd.Series(['2010-01-01', '2011-11-30'])
res = (pd.to_datetime('today') - pd.to_datetime(s)).mean()

# Timedelta('2815 days 23:39:13.331568')
```

Answer (score 1):

`date.today()` is a `date`, while the `x` in `age` are all `datetime`s. Change `date.today()` to `datetime.today()` and the error should go away.